# Producing statistics on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I want to show my users some statistics such as hits/second on Google App Engine. I started to roll my own:

- On each page view, add 1 to a count in memcache.

Each minute:

- Read and reset the count and also set a "since" variable to now.
- Divide the number of hits by the amount of time since I last calculated.
- Save the data to an entity in the datastore.
- Throwing out data that's really old.

I then realised that this is non-trivial and there must be a library to do it, however I can't find one that works for me. I looked briefly at rrd4j and JRobin but I'm not sure they they're usable on Google App Engine without quite a lot of rewriting. Does anyone have any more ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to remember Twitter commons has what you need, but I don't know if they could be easily portable to GAE: https://github.com/twitter/commons

Comment: I wish that the Twitter stuff had better documentation but it looks like it does what I'm after. Unfortunately I've started writing my own now and I think it will be quicker to finish it than start again with Twitter but I can steal some stuff - like the BoundedQueue implementation which I was struggling to find too.

Answer (score 2):

Try new technique mentioned in this post http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2012/07/analyzing-your-google-app-engine-logs.html.

It requires some additional work but it's worth trying. I'm using Mache (java framework) to ingest appengine logs into BigQuery and BigQuery API to query for results. Now pick a fancy javascript charts library and impress your users. Very powerful, flexible and scalable solution.

Comment: Thanks for the info - it could potentially work for me but it's not really what I'm looking for. I'm assuming that submitting events as logs and then parsing the logs for those events will be more expensive than using the Memcache / Datastore combo that I described.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [ProdEagle](http://www.prodeagle.com/) works for you. I think they do pretty much exactly what you want, and I belive they also have logic for handling data that is deleted from memcache without making a big hole in your graph.

Comment: Whilst this is exactly what I'm looking for, I really want a library to handle it, not an external service.

Comment: Right, because you want to display it to your users, it's not an aggregated dashboard for operations. If you don't find an exact fit, you could still check out the ProdEagle libraries for inspiration and add persistence and presentation layer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/).  You can submit arbitrary events and then extract aggregate information from an API... or just use the provided charts & graphs.

Comment: I'm really hoping for a library to do that kind of stuff internally - the kind of code used to produce a service like that, not a service to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

Since no-one seems to have an answer for me, I'm going to assume that there's no common library for doing this and I'll have to write one. I'll open source it and link from here if it feels like good code.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [Google Analytics](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1008080). You'd just need to copy and paste some javascript into your templates.

Comment: Google Analytics is not suitable for what I'm doing. The hits/second was just an example.

Comment: What are the features you are looking for?

Comment: I want to submit a generic value or event to a system and then get realtime or very near realtime statistics back - for example how frequently an event happened in the last minute. They're not page hits as such and I need to get the data back into my app - not view it on a separate system.

Comment: @mjaggard, I don't know how you finally implemented this but would creating fresh counting shards and destroying the old ones every minute not have worked in this scenario?

Comment: Yes but I was hoping not to re-invent the wheel. The project died but I did get this statistics mostly working using task queues beforehand.